# How to set the size of the display in WebView component?

Tags: android

On PC browser, the display is well. But open in Andriod webview, the display becomes very small. How to set the size of the display in WebView component?

Phone Display:

[image]

PC Display:

[image]

Comment: Need more details. Is your web page somewhere online so folks can check it out? Do you have screenshots as to what you're seeing? Do you have a minimal HTML test case that shows what's wrong?

Comment: I can just double click to zoom it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is not about android, but about Web. I think you can add this in your web html:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0,
          maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
```